# string combine and split algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, redis

I am using redis storing data, datas are combinated sequences of values, a sequece is combined with separator `:` and several string values, for example:

```
value1:value2:value3
```

the problem is those values may contain `:` in them, my first thought is escaping `:` to `::` in the values, and then combine them, and I can split them by a solo `:`.

but this is not perfect, because `{'abc', 'aaa:', 'bbb'}` will be escaped to `{'abc', 'aaa::', 'bbb'}` and combined to `abc:aaa:::bbb`, it's unresolveable. this is probably a stupid question, I'm stuck, how would you solve the problem, or any better suggestion ?

Comment: Use another separator that is unlikely to be in your values. Or use a list.

Comment: the sequence is an item of a list, It would be too much lists if I store each sequence as a list. @SergioTulentsev

Comment: Does your split method supports regular expressions?

Comment: I solved it, I first escape `:` in values to `\:` and combine them, and I can split the sequence by `(?<!\\):`, and then unescape `\:` in substrings to `:`

Answer (score 0):

I would instead suggest enclosing the values while inserting using a special identifier towards the beginning and end of string each and then combining them. e.g :

```
{'%abc%', '%aaa:%', '%bbb%'}
```

So whenever you want to split them again you can split them using your separator and then replace the prepended and appended value as per you convention to get the original string.

Hope that Helps!